# kafka ksql extract json fleld literal dollar symbol

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I've got a data stream coming from the mongo CDC connector, but the trouble is that the stream key is in the form of a JSON string.

e.g.
`{"id":"{ \"$oid\" : \"5bbb0c70cd0b9c06cf06c9c1\"}"}`

I know that I can use extractjsonfield method to extract the data using jsonpath, however, I can't figure out how to extract the literal dollar symbol I've tried:
`$.id.$oid`
`$.id[\$oid]`
`$.id.*`

each time I get a null response, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that your problem is related to [issue #1403](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/1403). 
You can use `[\\" field_name \\"]` to reference the column. For example,

```
SELECT EXTRACTJSONFIELD(test,'$[\\"$oid\\"]') FROM testing;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue with Debezium MongoDB Connector.
Using `[\\" field_name \\"]` as @Giorgos pointed didn't work for me with ksqlDB 0.21.0

Instead `[\" field_name \"]` (single back slash) works.